# How do I resolve a connectivity issue to Google Cloud using SSH?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I am doing my first project on Google Cloud, accessing SSH using the SSH dropdown on my VM instance and was going through the steps to set up the environment to use FileZilla to copy my project, apparently, I waited too long as I was setting up FileZilla and my SSH session timed out.  Since then every time I try to access SSH, I get the following error message:

Code: 1006
Please ensure you can make a proper https connection to the IAP for TCP hostname: https://tunnel.cloudproxy.app
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

This started happening around midnight last night and still going on this morning.  I have searched and followed all the instructions pointed out on this link:

https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

and the problem persists. I have even stopped, started, and reset the VM instance which did not resolve the issue.  I am hoping someone has any other suggestions I can follow beyond what can be found on this site already.

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

**UPDATE:**. I still haven't found the solution, but I have found a way to access my instance through my local terminal on my MacBook using the gcloud command from the Google Cloud SDK.

**UPDATE:** I did some research and I found that I had to delete my access keys and create new ones and it solved the problem.

Comment: Please update your question with specific details of the steps you're following, including adding a hyperlink to the "steps" that you're following, and how you're SSH'ing to the instance. It's curious that you are receiving errors that reference [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap) as I would not expect you to be using this service.

Comment: Your question still lacks much detail. You suggest that this was working and stopped at midnight. Are you confident you didn't change any of your settings? You suggest that you're SSH'ing through the browser-based Cloud Console, have you tried closing the browser and restarting it? You haven't for example added an external IP address to your instance? You haven't deleted the firewall rule permitting IAM (`35.235.240.0/20`) on port 22? It's difficult to diagnose with so little detail.

Comment: As a "first project", it's great that you're taking such a strong stance on security by using IAP to tunnel to your VM but this may be adding complexity that's overwhelming you. It's entirely possible (and less secure) to not use IAP and simply add an external IP to your isntance. It is **less** secure but, for learning purposes...

Comment: @DazWilkin I haven't deleted the rule permitting IAM, in fact I have created it after I have gotten the error.  I have also tried closing the browser and restarted it, but neither of those solved the problem.

Comment: @DazWilkin I also didn't add an external IP address to my instance.

Comment: I'm outta suggestions. You're confident this was working and without changing anything, it's no longer working. That troubles me. There is a [caveat](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#known_limitations) on the doc's page that discourages bulk transfer across IAP and your questions suggests you're using FTP so that's a possibility perhaps (that you have been) but it's doesn't really square with your observations. Let's see whether others have suggestions.